# Why don't I get mobile adjusted responses while setting userAgent with puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to achieve similar results as inside of Network Tab of Google Chrome browser. I'm interested in sizes of website.

I wrote some code using nodejs and puppeteer where I manipulate userAgent header. I am quite sure that the header is properly set but instead of mobile version of an image from the web server I am keep getting desktop version. As an example take https:/www.nba.com/ 
When opening above webpage with google chrome as if it was viewed by iPhone device I get as one of responses mobile version of splash_screen.jpeg. When opening the very same website as if it was viewed from PC I get PC version of splash_screen.jpg. When I set exactly the same userAgents as in requests of Google Chrome with puppeteer there is no difference regarding responses

To setup userAgent I'm doing:

```
if (process.argv[4] == 'mobile') {
        await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1');
    } else {
        await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Mobile Safari/537.36');        
    }
```

To manipulate response I do:

```
page._client.on('Network.dataReceived', (event) => {
      const request = page._networkManager._requestIdToRequest.get(
        event.requestId
      );
      if (request && request.url().startsWith('data:')) {
        return;
      }

      // some extra stuff down here
    });
```

I expect my output to be the same as it is in Network Tab of Google Chrome browser. Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to set the [viewport](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetviewportviewport), not (or, as well as) the user agent, in order to see the 'mobile' version of a site.

Comment: Wow, it turns out that it actually works :) I additionally set isMobile property to true. Thanks for your help  @nahanil